# Axios error when sending api request to Discord

Tags: axios, discord

I'm trying to send an automated message to discord from my account token using the axios client, it worked on a different project of mine but it doesn't work on a brand new project for some reason. Here is the code so far:

```js
const axios = require('axios').default;

async function Post() {
    const URL = `https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/${process.env.CHANNEL}/messages`
    const payload = { content: "This message has been sent using axios!" }

    await axios.post(URL, payload, { headers: { 'authorization': process.env.TOKEN } })
}

Post();
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
node:internal/errors:464
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_HEADER_VALUE]: Invalid value "undefined" for header "authorization"
    at ClientRequest.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:579:3)
    at new ClientRequest (node:_http_client:256:14)
    at Object.request (node:https:353:10)
    at RedirectableRequest._performRequest (/home/nonce/Documents/Repositories/test/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:279:24)
    at new RedirectableRequest (/home/nonce/Documents/Repositories/test/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:61:8)
    at Object.request (/home/nonce/Documents/Repositories/test/node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:482:14)
    at dispatchHttpRequest (/home/nonce/Documents/Repositories/test/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:232:25)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at httpAdapter (/home/nonce/Documents/Repositories/test/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:48:10)
    at dispatchRequest (/home/nonce/Documents/Repositories/test/node_modules/axios/lib/core/dispatchRequest.js:58:10) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_INVALID_HEADER_VALUE'
}
```

And for the record, I'm not trying to create a spammer or anything that breaks Discord's API rules.

Here are the versions I'm using, if it helps in any way:

`node`: v16.13.2

`npm`: v8.1.2

`axios`: v0.25.0

Comment: Did you read the error?

Comment: @Travis yes I have, but the process.env.TOKEN environment variable should work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error, I forgot to add the `dotenv` package all along.